# Is all Multi-index data stored in memory

Tags: multi-index

I wanna know is all index data stored in memory?Is so, what if the BP suffer from ddos attack? and how to store data on disk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, but you only need to store the current state.
2. There are 21 main BPs and many standby BPs that all have the same and redundantly updated RAM state.  EOSIO is built specific to thwart a ddos from causing a significant impact on the network.
3. Read the IPFS wp for storage:

https://github.com/EOSIO/Documentation/blob/master/EOS.IO%20Storage.pdf

See more about multi index: https://developers.eos.io/eosio-cpp/docs/db-api